# CFEclipse and Eclipse PDT coexisting?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to have Eclipse PDT and CFEclipse installed on the same machine? Seems that PDT gets overwritten when I install CFEclipse on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to have them both installed, but it messed up my perspectives and config settings. I suppose I'll have to use Dreamweaver unless there is another way to have this work (not buying CFBuilder).